# calling a function from within a lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Is there a way to call a function from within a lambda expression?

we currently have the following

```
 var obj = m.Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.ColumnName, y => y.ColumnValue))
             .ToList();


private static string BuildNewContent(EnumColumnType columnType, String columnValue, List<TableColumn> CurrentRow)
    {
}
```

so what we really want to do is add the returned value from BuildNewContent as the value for the dictionary.
so something like the following:-

```
var obj = m.Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.ColumnName, BuildNewContent(y => y.ColumnType, y=> y.ContentValue, y)))
             .ToList();
```

I realize that we can easily achieve this via simply looping, however, we would like to see how to do this using Lambda (if possible)

UPDATE - As requested the type of M is a TableViewModel which is a nested list

```
public class TableViewModel 
{
   public List<List<TableColumn>> Grid { get; set; }
}

 public class TableColumn
{
    public TableColumn() { }

    public TableColumn(string columnHeader, string columnValue, int columnWidth, EnumColumnType columnType, string columnName)
    {
        this.ColumnHeader = columnHeader;
        this.ColumnValue = columnValue;
        this.ColumnWidth = columnWidth;
        this.ColumnType = columnType;
        this.ColumnName = columnName;
    }

    public string               ColumnHeader    { get; set; }
    public string               ColumnName      { get; set; }
    public string               ColumnValue     { get; set; }
    public int                  ColumnWidth     { get; set; }
    public EnumColumnType       ColumnType      { get; set; }  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you had it almost right

```
var obj = m.Select(x => x.ToDictionary(
    y => y.ColumnName, y => BuildNewContent(y.ColumnType, y.ContentValue, y))).ToList();
```

however I suspect that instead of the last `y` parameter you want to provide `x` or some other value, since `y` probably isn't of type `List<TableColumn>`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with what you've tried is just the arguments to the `BuildNewContent` method - you're providing lambda expressions when they should just be values. So I suspect you want:

```
var obj = m.Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.ColumnName,
                               BuildNewContent(y.ColumnType, y.ContentValue, y)))
           .ToList();
```

It's not clear what the type of `y` is, so it's hard to know whether this will really just work immediately, but it's certainly *entirely* feasible to call a method within a lambda expression.

However, this *will* fail at execution time if `m` is something like a LINQ to SQL table - in that case, the LINQ provide will need to try to convert the expression tree (that the compiler has created from the lambda expression) into SQL, and it doesn't know what `BuildNewContent` is meant to do. If it's just LINQ to Objects, that's fine.